# How to open multiple whatsapp web session?

Tags: whatsapp

I have to provide a double software assistance service, each software has its phone number and I want to enable whatsapp business to support customers.
My question is, how can I handle multiple sessions?
I have discarded the anonymous browser option due to the fact I would reopen the session every day.
The only other solution is to use different browsers, but I don't think it is so handy.
Is there any other solution? Maybe a browser plugin or something like that?

Comment: Here are some links to assist https://www.certitudenews.com/7-chrome-extensions-for-managing-multiple-login-sessions/. If yiu are using the same chrome profile for all sessions you may need to look at Cookie Profile Switcher.  Haven't tried any of the attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found RAMBOX https://rambox.app/ and it seems exactly what I need.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).